# Django: Find element in list by value

Tags: django, list, django-templates

I have a sorted list of objects that I want my users to select a range from. For this I added two `select` elements (called `from` and `to`)to my web page. `from` is filled directly from the list, like this:

```
<select id="from">
    {% for el in el_list %}<option>{{el.number}}</option>{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Once a value has been selected in `from` I'd like to populate `to` with the values from the selected value until the last one.

The list is sorted by the `number` attribute on python's side so I guess all I need to do is find the selected element in the list, slice the list accordingly and use the rest to populate my second `select`.

I've searched the documentation and several snippets but so far I've only found filters giving me the last or the first element of a list. I also know I can check if the selected value is in my list using `in`, but how can I then get that object's index?

I know I could probably run along the whole list with a `for` ... `if`, but I am almost sure there's a more elegant method out there, that I simply haven't found yet.

If any of you could provide me with a few pointers on how to solve this more elegantly it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're looking through template tags for this. They won't help: by the time the user sees the page to select something from the `from` select, the template has already been rendered. You need to use Javascript.

Comment: I use Javascript to catch the change event and populate the second `select`, but I thought I'd get the actual data that I fill the select with via the django template.

Comment: I gave up, got the list of values via the first `select`'s options array and did the rest in Javascript as per your suggestion.